# pg_dump: abortando debido a que no coincide la versión del servidor

Tags: postgresql

Desde hace un tiempo he estado utilizando un script para realizar los respaldos de postgres pero desde que se actualizó la versión del servidor me da el siguiente error:

```html
pg_dump: versión del servidor: 9.4.18; versión de pg_dump: 8.4.20
pg_dump: abortando debido a que no coincide la versión del servidor
```

No entiendo cual pueda ser el problema, a continuación dejo el script del respaldo, agradezco cualquier ayuda.

```html
#!/bin/bash

HOME=/
PG_USER=usuario
DATABASE=basededados
SERVER=SERVER
DIR="Directorio a respaldar"
DATE=$(date +"%m_%d_%y")
FILE="$DATABASE_$DATE"
# pass @ .pgpass

PG_BAK_NOW () {
  pg_dump -h $SERVER -U $PG_USER $DATABASE -f $FILE.sql
}

echo "Ready to dump to $FILE" >> "$HOME/pg_status"

cd $DIR
if [ -f "$FILE" ];
then
  rm $FILE
  PG_BAK_NOW
else
  PG_BAK_NOW
fi
```

Comment: No estoy seguro pero si mal no recuerdo me pasó algo similar y tenía que ver con que la versión anterior de tu postgres queda como "vigente" en el PATH del sistema entonces al ejecutar tu script el primer paso que se hace es el chequeo de versiones y como no coincide tu versión actual de postgres con aquella suministrada en el PATH arroja ese error. Actualiza el PATH con la versión nueva de tu postgres y debería solucionarse. Espero esto te ayude a solucionarlo, Un saludo

Comment: Como puedo verificar que ese sea el problema y como puedo hacer el cambio del path, busco en google y realmente no consigo nada relevante.

Comment: GNU/Linux Centos 6.9, por ahi leí que usara la opción -i para que ignore las versiones pero no se que tan seguro sea ese procedimiento.

Comment: No creo que surja efecto lo de ignorar versiones porque el problema me parece que está en que linux está apuntando a la versión antigua de postgres para guardar data, sin embargo, tu script está implementando la versión nueva de tu postgres y es probable que por ese conflicto es que tengas el error

Comment: La version que me muestra es la 9.4.18

Comment: la verdad no, pero el error arroja que es la 8.4.20, "pg_dump: versión del servidor: 9.4.18; versión de pg_dump: 8.4.20"

Answer (score 1):

Yo esto lo resolví de la siguiente manera:

Como en el path por defecto tenia el pg_dump de la versión "vieja", busque donde estan los binarios de postgres (asumo linux porque veo el script bash, y en mi caso uso debian):

```
$ locate pg_dump
...
/usr/lib/postgresql/11/bin/pg_dump                
/usr/lib/postgresql/11/bin/pg_dumpall
/usr/lib/postgresql/9.3/bin/pg_dump
/usr/lib/postgresql/9.3/bin/pg_dumpall
/usr/lib/postgresql/9.4/bin/pg_dump
/usr/lib/postgresql/9.4/bin/pg_dumpall
/usr/lib/postgresql/9.6/bin/pg_dump
/usr/lib/postgresql/9.6/bin/pg_dumpall
...
```

Entonces para que coincidan las versiones del servidor, usé el path absoluto del binario que corresponda

En tu caso, la linea del script debería ser:

```
/usr/lib/postgresql/9.4/bin/pg_dump -h $SERVER -U $PG_USER $DATABASE -f $FILE.sql
```